# jQuery remove option from select list where variable has spaces

Tags: jquery

On my page, when the user clicks a 'delete' button, an item from a select list which matches the variable is deleted and the dom is updated.
This works fine unless the variable in question has a space in it.

```
 $('option[value='+popupSelect+']').remove();
```

If **popupSelect = nospaces** this will work.

If **popupSelect = has spaces** this will not work and I will get the following console error:

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=has spaces]*

I've tried all kinds of quote arrangements but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Syntax issue. Youre missing quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it with `"`:

```
$('option[value="'+popupSelect+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: argh! I swear I thought I had tried this. This is correct!

Answer (score 4):

When your *attribute equal selector* has special character, you have to wrap them in quote :

```
$('option[value="'+popupSelect+'"]')
```

Be aware of you current string quotes. For instance, in this example using unescaped `'` would end your string and throw an error.

Comment: thanks, this is correct. I marked @omeinusch answer as the answer as his came in first.